# pass id of html element to php

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to send a variable from a html element to php with ajax. It's a button, so the value property cannot be used to assign a variable. Is it possible to send it's id property to a php file with jquery or would there be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to send the ID field of an element to a server with jQuery, you can do the following:

```
myButton = $(".some.selector.that.finds.the .button")
$.post("http://myserver.com/myfile.php", {theID: myButton.attr('id')});
```

If you want to store data along with that element, use the `data-` property like so:

**HTML:**

```
<button name="mybutton" data-extra="blahblahblah...">
```

**Javascript:**

```
myButton = $(".some.selector.that.finds.the .button")
$.post("http://myserver.com/myfile.php", {myData: myButton.data('extra')});
```

Answer (score 2):

Very easy to do with ajax. Used $.post for example, can change to $.get also

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$( selector ).click( function(){
    $.post( url, { id: this.id} , function( data){
        /* do something here on ajax success*/
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ID, or use a `data-` attribute on the button to store what you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

use hidden input element. set them and then read them in php